# Internet connection through command line

Tags: command-line, internet, ethernet, authentication

The system loses institute internet connection after some time due to session time out. How to bring it up using the terminal.

Comment: What is the system?

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.